# How to decrease space height (margin) between equations

Tags: equations, captions, margins, lyx, elsarticle

I want to decrease spaces(margin) height before and after equations because I found big space when text end and display formula appears or between equations each in separate line.

Also I want to do the same between caption text and table there is also big space.

All of this in `elsarticle` class.

Comment: Could you please export a *small* example LyX document to LaTeX and post this as part of your question? Even include the current output that you don't like. There are ways of changing these lengths, but it would be clear what you're after with some visual aid.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to put the following after `\begin{document}`:

```
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\abovedisplayshortskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayshortskip=0pt
```

The "short" skips correspond to equations after a short line.

For the captions:

```
\abovecaptionskip=0pt
\belowcaptionskip=0pt
```

Comment: Do you know what are the default values for these arguments?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the following to reduce the spacing between equation display and the rest of the text.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{4pt}}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\belowdisplayskip{4pt}}
```